# crash with CoreAudioDevice

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, settings

Hello I have an WPF application in C# which shall overwrite the systems settings of the speaker volume. for this I use:

```
public void SetAudioVolume(int nVol)
{
       CoreAudioDevice defaultPlaybackDevice = new CoreAudioController().DefaultPlaybackDevice;            
        defaultPlaybackDevice.Volume = nVol;
}
```

With Windows 10 it works fine but when I run the program at windows 7 my application crashes. It seems this methode isn't working at Win7. Is there any other way to set the system speaker and microphone settings to maximum in my application?

Edited:

For some unknown reason I don't get a log entry even though the exception is catched. But when I look at the minidmp I see this:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "Could not load file or assembly
>   'AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio, Version=3.0.0.209, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=fda5729e2db3a64f' or one of its

Does anybody know what I have to install so that it is working at Win7 too?

Comment: "my application crashes", that's because it's throwing an exception. Learn to use `try-catch` and post the real exception message here

Comment: I added the information